# getOutputStream() has already been called for this response in Spring Application

Tags: spring, exception, servlets, response

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:626)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:215)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:125)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:118)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:190)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:123)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:80)
    org.apache.jsp.tiles.baseLayout_jsp._jspService(baseLayout_jsp.java:149)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:690)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:81)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:359)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:275)
    org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:344)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:272)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:81)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the exception clearly states, the `getOutputStream()` method can only be called on a response **once**. You're attempting to do it more than once which is why you're getting that exception - you'll need to figure out where in your code that's happening and fix it.